# Making a row clickable

Tags: javascript, jsp

i am working with jsp and i had a table in that i retrieved data from database and my problem is how to make a table row clickable . and my knowledge in jquery is nothing. so plz try to help me in javascript.

```
    <table class="main" align="center" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td class="did">Dealer Id</td>
        <td class="dname">Dealer Name</td>
        <td class="door">Door no</td>
        <td class="strt">Street</td>
        <td class="city">City</td>
        <td class="dst">District</td>
        <td class="state">State</td>
        <td class="mob">Mobile</td>
        <td class="cntPer">Contact Person</td>
        <td class="phne">Phone No</td>

      </tr>
      </table>
      <div class="overflow">
      <table class="main scroll" align="center" border="1">
      <% while (rs.next()) {%>
      <tr>
        <td class="did"><%=rs.getString("deal_id_v") %></td>
        <td class="dname"><%=rs.getString("deal_name_v")%></td>
        <td class="door"><%=rs.getString("deal_door_no_v")%></td>
        <td class="strt"><%=rs.getString("deal_street_v")%></td>
        <td class="city"><%=rs.getString("deal_city_v")%></td>
        <td class="dst"><%= rs.getString("deal_district_v")%></td>
        <td class="state"><%=rs.getString("deal_state_v")%></td>
        <td class="mob"><%=rs.getString("deal_mobile_no_v")%></td>
        <td class="cntPer"><%=rs.getString("deal_contactperson_v")%></td>
        <td class="phne"><%=rs.getString("deal_phone_no_v")%></td>

      </tr>
      <%}
      %>
     </table>
     </div>
```

Comment: select the table row using selector, and just write the click function to that...

Comment: Add some specification on it.First give your proper requirement.if you just want to make your table row clickable then just user selector and class jquery click function().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this

```
$(".main tr").click(funnction() {
   // code here after click
})
```

as an example if you want to read the contents of a `td` then you would do like below,

```
$(".main tr").click(funnction() {
   alert( $(this).find('did').html());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this site helps you to solve your problem

```
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquey-make-entire-table-row-clickable/
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
<tbody>
   <tr class='clickableRow' href='url://'>
                    <td>Blah Blah</td>
                    <td>1234567</td>
                    <td>£158,000</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".clickableRow").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).attr("href");
  });
});
```

Comment: I suggest for valid html use data-href instead of href.